# How to add number to sqlite3 column values

Tags: python, sqlite

Am able to to successfully update `sqlite3` column values with this function

```
fgr = 1043

con = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.executescript("UPDATE '{}' SET BALANCE=BALANCE+50".format(fgr))
con.commit()
con.close()
```

What i want to update it using the `row Id` greater than `4`, when i run the function it execute successfully but when the check the data in the `column` no changes has been applied.

**Funtion**

```
fgr = 1043

con = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.executescript("UPDATE '{}' SET BALANCE=BALANCE+50".format(fgr))
cur.executescript("UPDATE '{}' SET BALANCE=BALANCE+50 WHERE ID > ?".format(fgr, (4),))
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: Are you certain that there are any matching records?

Comment: Your second one includes 4 as a format arg when the only one should be the table name. The value 4 should be in the second argument to `execute()` (**not** `executescript()`) so it gets bound to the parameter in the query.

Comment: You should also be using double quotes around your table name, not single quotes. The former says it's an identifier, the latter that it's a string.

Comment: Also, using a number like 1043 as your table name is going to really confuse people and be really error prone. Use sensible meaningful names for tables and columns.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are building your update query incorrectly.  Try this version:

```
fgr = 1043
ID = 4
cur.executescript("UPDATE \"" + fgr + "\" SET BALANCE = BALANCE + 50 WHERE ID > ?", (ID,))
```

If the above still update no records, then maybe you don't have any matching records in your SQLite database.  Try to confirm this by running the following select:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 1043
WHERE ID > 4;
```

Comment: @OJOE Try putting the table name in double quotes.